# Animation issue on X11 window

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm struggling to get X11 redrawing events right in a cross platform C++ application.

Everything works great on Windows (I just issue some `InvalidateRect` calls when I need the window to redraw), but on Linux I keep having redrawing stuttering (probably when I send too many redraw events as follows)

```
event.type = Expose;
event.xexpose.window = window;
XSendEvent(display, window, False, ExposureMask, &event);
```

the same happens when I resize the window.

This is the code I'm using

```
void Window::redraw() { // Called by any control which needs redrawing
  XEvent event;
  memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
  event.type = Expose;
  event.xexpose.display = display;
  XSendEvent(display, window, False, ExposureMask, &event);
}

void Window::resize(int width, int height) {
  this->Width = width;
  this->Height = height;
}

bool Window::wndProc(XEvent *evt) {
  switch (evt->type) {

      case Expose: {

        if (evt->xexpose.count == 0) { // handle last one only

            if (Width != Bitmap.width() || Height != Bitmap.height())
              Bitmap.resize(Width, Height);

          Renderer.drawOnBitmap(Bitmap);

          this->paint();
        }

        return true;

      } break;

      case ConfigureNotify: {
        this->resize(evt->xconfigure.width, evt->xconfigure.height);

        redraw();
        return true;
      } break;
  }
}

void Window::paint() {

    XImage image;
    sk_bzero(&image, sizeof(image));

//    .. boilerplate to initialize XImage...

    XInitImage(&image);
    XPutImage(display, window, fGc, &image,
              0, 0,
              0, 0,
              Width, Height);
}
```

I tried several approaches to solve this issue including:

- Having a 200 ms delay between every redraw event sending (stuttering still happening.. resize still issues a LOT of events)
- Having a secondary thread issuing a redraw call every 50ms (this saturates X11's buffer immediately and crashes the whole thing)

Unfortunately I have **animated controls** which call `redraw()` anytime they need another redrawing of part of the window (I handle painting regions of the window separately).

How can I solve stuttering during resizing and too many redrawing events while ensuring my animated controls remain smooth?

Comment: First, try playing with `XCheckTypedWindowEvent`. If you have several expose events in the queue for your window, you probably should only process one. Second, try limiting the redraw  rate (if the next redraw event comes faster than 20 ms after the previous one, don't repaint). Last but not least, switch to some other rendering engine (OpenGL? XPutImage can be slow). Profile your program!

Comment: Thanks! I'll gladly accept this as an answer if you post it. Would using openGL be faster with complex UIs? I thought XPutImage was like a BitBlt on Windows (quite fast, it just has to copy stuff over)

Comment: Heh, check that it works first.

Comment: It does, I'll look into openGL-ing the thing since you said it could be faster, but for now it works great. Make that an answer please!

Comment: So what exactly caused performance to improve?

Comment: Using XCheckTypedWindowEvent on the ConfigureNotify messages. I'm trying to switch to openGL but the same fix didn't work in that case (I'm wondering why..)