# X11 window resizing stutters

Tags: linux, opengl, x11

I'm creating an openGL window in X11 and using `glxswapbuffers` for double buffering.

The problem is: rendering seems fine but I get openGL contents bouncing around and the window border stuttering when resizing.

I tried filtering the ConfigureNotify events, delaying them, setting vsync off with `glXSwapInterval`... nothing worked.

This is the code I'm using

```
void Window::redraw() { // Called by any control which needs redrawing
  XEvent event;
  memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
  event.type = Expose;
  event.xexpose.display = display;
  XSendEvent(display, window, False, ExposureMask, &event);
}

void Window::resize(int width, int height) {
  this->Width = width;
  this->Height = height;
}

bool Window::wndProc(XEvent *evt) {
  switch (evt->type) {

      case Expose: {

        if (evt->xexpose.count == 0) { // handle last one only

          while (XCheckTypedWindowEvent(display, window, Expose, evt));

            if (Width != oldWidth || Height != oldHeight)
              resizeViewportAndUpdateDimensions();

          Renderer.drawGLStuff();

          this->redraw();
        }

        return true;

      } break;

      case ConfigureNotify: {
        this->resize(evt->xconfigure.width, evt->xconfigure.height);

        this->redraw();
        return true;
      } break;
  }
}
```

Notice that this is a different issue (strictly linked to resizing) than [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36365528/3834459) which I solved via `XCheckTypedWindowEvent`.

Comment: This happens in other window systems as well, just so you know (e.g. Win32 and Quartz). While resizing the framebuffer is damaged and its contents are undefined. You'd need to respond to damage while simultaneously processing resize messages and that doesn't often work intuitively.

Comment: In Win32, for example, you actually have to setup a secondary thread to pump rendering because Windows stops sending events while the user is dragging the frame and you'll only get new messages once released.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thanks, but how to `respond to damage`? What does that mean?

Comment: Damage refers to the contents of a window being invalidated. It can happen because another window moves over top it (generally not a problem with compositing window managers) or because the window was resized. Redrawing is usually what you do to respond to damage, but resize events are often modal. I'd love to give an actual answer but I've only dealt with this problem in OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/configure.html

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structure-control/resize.html

From what I can read from those two links ConfigureNotify happens when a change has completed. ResizeRequest happens when a resize is attempted. Specifically:

> The X server can report ResizeRequest events to clients wanting
>   information about another client's attempts to change the size of a
>   window.

I don´t like the sound of "CAN report", but I suppose you should give it a shot. Don´t forget to set proper event bit as instructed in the link. As for what you should do when capturing event I´m not too sure... I would clear the front buffer and await resize to complete.