# X11 in C++ - Cropping happens whenever ResizeRedirectMask is set when the window is resized

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, xorg

## Story

I've made a simple drawing program displaying graphics using **X11/Xlib** for a **Linux system**.

*It has a menu and an editor to make drawings.*

It needs to know the size of the window, so, at first, I used `XGetWindowAttributes()`
but, I found it **too slow for my taste**.

Since I executed the function each frames, my program was slow.

Then, I *tried* to run the function **less often**, *something like every 4 frames* but it is caused a **flickering**.

I wanted an event that could be generated each time the window's size changed to **run the function only on size change**.

## Original fix:

I've found `ResizeRequest` which **does what I want** and outputs the window's size as bonus.
So I didn't needed `XGetWindowAttributes()` any more. This **speeded up the program a lot.**
It works well when resizing down the window.

## New Issue:

I've found that when the windows is **resized bigger** *than the original size*, every objects **drawn outside** of original range gets **cropped** as shown in the image.

[image: Cropped Image]

We can see the grey borders that **should be all around the window but are cropped** *all in black*. It's visible especially for the *top right* colour palette which has 16 colours but **4 colours are half-cropped** and **8 aren't visible** at all here.

---

## What I would like to do:

I would like to know how to fix the cropping issue by maybe solving one of the following questions:

1. If I must **approve resizing** *when the event is sent*, how can I do?
2. If I must mess with **buffers**, how can I do?

---

## Tracks:

My program has a menu that still uses `XGetWindowAttributes()`, and the editor *(shown in the image)* uses the `ResizeRequest` event, *which is faster than `XGetWindowAttributes()`*.
As expected, the cropping happens in the editor and not in the menu.
But I noticed that I can **change the window's size without cropping** if I change it in the menu then in the editor, and **it works**!

I then found that **the cropping happens whenever `ResizeRedirectMask` is set** in the `XSelectInput()` function.

As quoted from [Xlib Programming Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structure-control/resize.html) at the 10.11.4 ResizeRequest Events page.

> Any attempts to change the size by other clients are then **redirected**.

I guess, that means it won't affect windows size (which is true as I tested with `XGetWindowAttributes()` in parallel). So, then **I must approve the resizing but how?**

As quoted from the answer of [X11 window resizing stutters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414716/x11-window-resizing-stutters/36435650?r=SearchResults#36435650).

> I would **clear the front buffer** and await resize to complete.

**How can I do that?**

---

## Sample Code:

I've made a short program that display random colored squares everywhere, even outside of the window. **The program runs if you copy it.**

**There is a `#if` statement that you can change to see the difference** between expected (`false`) and reality (`true`)

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <unistd.h>

#if true //Make it true to set ResizeRedirectMask and false to disable.
    #define Masks KeyPressMask|ResizeRedirectMask
#else
    #define Masks KeyPressMask
#endif

int main(){
    uint32_t RDM=0;

    uint16_t i=0;

    bool RunLoop=true;

    Display* XDisplay=XOpenDisplay(0);//Create a display
    Window XWindow=XCreateSimpleWindow(XDisplay,DefaultRootWindow(XDisplay),0,0,480,360,0,0,0);//Create a Window
    XMapWindow(XDisplay,XWindow);//Make the Window visible
    GC XGraphicCTX=XCreateGC(XDisplay,XWindow,0,0);//Create a Graphics Context

    //v Wait for a MapNotify XEvent for next commands
    XSelectInput(XDisplay,XWindow,StructureNotifyMask);
    while(1){
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(XDisplay,&e);
        if(e.type==MapNotify)break;
    }
    XSelectInput(XDisplay,XWindow,Masks); //Here is part of the magic error
    while(RunLoop){
        while(XPending(XDisplay)){//Get key changes
            XEvent Event;
            XNextEvent(XDisplay,&Event);
            if(Event.type==KeyPress){
                RunLoop=false;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<4096;i++){
            RDM=(RDM+1841)*9245;    //Not perfect but good enough
            XSetForeground(XDisplay,XGraphicCTX,RDM&0xFFFFFF);
            
            RDM=(RDM+1841)*9245;    //Not perfect but good enough
            XFillRectangle(XDisplay,XWindow,XGraphicCTX,RDM&0xFFFF,(RDM>>16),64,64);
        }

        XFlush(XDisplay);

        usleep(16667); //AHHH there is 666!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is as follows **when resized**:
[image: Unexpected result of New Program]

As we can see, **cropping happens whenever `ResizeRedirectMask` is set**, you don't even need to respond to the event to make it happening!
Toggling the `#if` statement to `false` **gives the desired behaviour** since it would disable `ResizeRedirectMask`.
That particular program doesn't care of the window's size, **most of my programs need to know the size or it fails**.

---

## Some details:

I **used to** get the size of the window using `XGetWindowAttributes()` *which a bit slow*, I **still use it in the menu** *as it works good enough*.
That's why in the editor, I use the `ResizeRequest` event.

The `ConfigureNotify` event **seems** to works greatly but it **flickers way more** than by using `XGetWindowAttributes()`.
Why does it flickers?
It flickers because a `ConfigureNotify` is sent **after the resize completed**, it means that it as **generally sent one frame after** the resize.
This is linked to [X11 Window Resizing Stutters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414716/x11-window-resizing-stutters/36435650?r=SearchResults#36435650).
**At least, it doesn't wastes a lot of performances.**
I'm looking for a way to fix the flickering as it could be easier.

Note that the question completely changed because the issue is different than originally. But still in link with the original issue.

Comment: First, I'd try to avoid Xlib and use XCB instead, but that's probably a bit far. Then, I think you can get actual notifications when the size changes, that way you don't have to repeatedly poll a value that never changed.

Comment: Please show your code if you'd like assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Another trick here would be to only poll something that expensive occasionally, rather than every tick.  Or set to a specific size and then react to resize events (which I find to be vastly preferable across a variety of languages and situations).

Comment: Please ask one question per question. Do not change the question completely because you have found a solution and now you have a new problem. If you have found an answer to the original question, **post it**. Then ask a new question.

Comment: The code is simple, see the title "Cropping happens whenever ResizeRedirectMask is set". I guess it's enough!

Comment: Sorry, I must recycle questions also because of Stack Overflow's laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResizeRedirectMask` is irrelevant for your purposes. You never want it unless you are writing a window manager. You need `StructureNotifyMask`. You should virtually always select this mask (maybe unless your window never gets resized).

If you do not select `StructureNotifyMask`, your window never gets actual resize events and does not get a chance to respond to them.

When you get a `ConfigureNotify` event, which will only happen if you select `StructureNotifyMask`, it will contain the new actual geometry, so your window can update itself.

Comment: Is it normal it flickers so much? I've tried that and it works but it flickers more than with the old method (`XGetWindowAttributes()`). I guess it has one frame of latency between the actual resize and the event.
It is same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414716/x11-window-resizing-stutters/36435650#36435650

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Your sample program doesn't really flicker at all. Resize invalidates the buffer, so each time it is resized, the drawing starts from a blank canvass. If you want to keep the old picture, you need to keep the old picture *somewhere* and redraw it upon resize.

Comment: The whole buffer is invalidated simply because the default is to forget the old buffer. To keep the old contents, set window attribute `bit_gravity` to something other than `ForgetGravity`. This of course will not keep the off-screen parts.

Comment: I tried everything (`bit_gravity` and `backing store`) and it still flickers a bit. I even re-wrote the initialization of the first program I shown and changed the behaviour at window change and it still loose content or flickers. I guess it's good enough for that question and I'll do a new one focusing one that problem.

Comment: Eventually, I found the solution. It was a simple issue. I needed to put the `CWBitGravity` valuemask in the `XCreateWindow()` function (that I now use instead of `WCreateSimpleWindow()`)